# How to change the state of the particular component when it is clicked, using useState in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am facing a problem when working with similar functional components in react js. Whenever I click on this icon it opens up every component related to it like this,
[image]

but what I want is to open the component only for the clicked one.
How can I achieve that?
 I am using useState over here to achieve this functionality
 And making a different state for every component does not make sense here.

**Code**
Here is a simple example of the current functionality

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


function Test1() {
  const [body, setBody] = useState(false);
  const showHideBody = () => {
    setBody(!body);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am header</div>

      {body ? <div className="body__container">I am body</div> : null}
      <button onClick={showHideBody}>{body ? "Hide body" : "Show Body"}</button>

      {body ? <div className="body__container">I am body</div> : null}
      <button onClick={showHideBody}>{body ? "Hide body" : "Show Body"}</button>
      {body ? <div className="body__container">I am body</div> : null}
      <button onClick={showHideBody}>{body ? "Hide body" : "Show Body"}</button>
      {body ? <div className="body__container">I am body</div> : null}
      <button onClick={showHideBody}>{body ? "Hide body" : "Show Body"}</button>
      {body ? <div className="body__container">I am body</div> : null}
      <button onClick={showHideBody}>{body ? "Hide body" : "Show Body"}</button>
      {body ? <div className="body__container">I am body</div> : null}
      <button onClick={showHideBody}>{body ? "Hide body" : "Show Body"}</button>
      <div>I am footer</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a separate component type for the components, each with their own state:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Component() {
  const [body, setBody] = useState(false);
  const showHideBody = () => {
    setBody(!body);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {body ? <div className="body__container">I am body</div> : null}
      <button onClick={showHideBody}>{body ? "Hide body" : "Show Body"}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Test1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am header</div>

      <Component />
      <Component />
      <Component />
      <Component />
      <Component />
      <Component />

      <div>I am footer</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test1;
```

Comment: Thanks @tmwilliamlin168 It was simple but could not think about it. Thank you